# Getting selected column/field for graduated color via expression or other routine in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression, choropleth

I have choropleth map with graduated colors. The column - **the field name** - that I choose **to define the classes** and the colors is important for my work on the maps. Is there a method to make it visible or refer to it at any other part of QGIS. It would be especially useful in the print composer, where I can check on other map objects and labels when I use several print composers. As far as I explored, there are only expressions to get values from the attribute table of certain layers or to get other layer properties than the style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable **Display classification attribute names** in the Canvas & Legend options in Settings | Options.

[image]

Comment: This is very useful! I think I can use this option for the legend from time to time.

Comment: To switch between visible and not visible I always have to navigate to the Settings and afterwards update the legend (reset to defaults). So I'm still curious if there is an expression to implement in a simple text label in the composer. This would be even better...

Answer (score -1):

Add a legend to the print composer. The graduated categories will be displayed with their corresponding classes.

[image]

Comment: I maybe was not clear enough. The legend displays only the classes, their style and the number of features in it. But not the name of the field chosen to define the classes. Even the subgroup title in the legend only refers to the name of the layer in the project.

Comment: Are you changing the field used to define the classes?

Comment: Yes, quite often, that's why I would be happy to check it without opening the style manager of the layer. But I do not need to change it somewhere else. It's only about refering to the name of the field, which is generating the graduated colors.